# Select the second last row in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to get the second last row of data on mysql. But my query only shows the last row.

```
SELECT news.news_title, news.news_details, news.news_author, news_images.filename
FROM news JOIN news_images 
ON news.news_title = news_images.news_title 
ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1` to get second last

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 2,1

Comment: sorry, but it still get the last row

Comment: @JoshuaC.Tuonan Do you want 2 last rows? Be more specific and create sample output.

Comment: @lad2025 Only the second last row

Comment: Prepare sample data with http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OFFSET` to get second last value like:

```
SELECT news.news_title, news.news_details, news.news_author, news_images.filename
FROM news JOIN news_images 
ON news.news_title = news_images.news_title 
ORDER BY news_id DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

`LIMIT number_of_rows OFFSET start_from`

If you want 2 last rows use: `LIMIT 2`.

**EDIT:**
Your question is very unclear but try:

```
SELECT t.news_title, t.news_details, t.news_author, ni.filename
FROM (SELECT news_title, news_details, news_author
      FROM news
      ORDER BY news_id DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS t
JOIN news_images ni
  ON t.news_title = ni.news_title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT news.news_title, news.news_details, news.news_author, news_images.filename
FROM news JOIN news_images 
ON news.news_title = news_images.news_title 
ORDER BY news_id DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

You should also refer [Select the nth Highest Record in a Database Table](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-nth-highest-record-database-table-using-mysql.aspx)